# Meteor.js calling specific data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So im making this inventory website, so the forklift drivers can add or remove weight from our inventory we measure our products in weight.

So basically I need to be able to fetch the weight (in kg) from mongo db and add it to it and save it

//edit
the problem I'm having is the current code is returning "NaN kg" in html

kg is defined by a number inserted into the db and i cant seem to get the kg value without my code running into a error

[image: This is the web part]
[image: This is the modal adding the kg value]

```
The Html      

     <form class="add-pro">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="namn" required="true" placeholder="Produkt Name"/>
      <br />
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" required="true" placeholder="Produkt code"/>
      <br />
      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="KG" name="kg" />
      <input id="btnModal" type="submit" value="add" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>



      <form class="add-data">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add-data-control" name="g" placeholder="how much">
        <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" type="submit" id="add-data-plus" aria-hidden="true"></button>
      </form>

Javascript

"submit .add-data": function(event){
  var g = event.target.g.value;
  var x = produkter.find().fetch();
  var k = kg;
  produkter.update(this._id, {$set: {kg: +k + +g }});
},


    Template.produkter.events({
"submit .add-pro": function(event){
var namn = event.target.namn.value;
var id = event.target.id.value;
var kg = event.target.kg.value;

produkter.insert({
  namn: namn,
  id: id,
  kg: kg
});
  return false;
```

},

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @Khang edited it to make it more clear i can give more info if needed

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code, see comments:

```
"submit .add-data": function(event){
  var g = event.target.g.value;
  var x = produkter.find().fetch();
// Where is kg defined?
  var k = kg;
// The expression +k + +g does not compute - do you mean k+g ?
  produkter.update(this._id, {$set: {kg: +k + +g }});
},
```

You may also be running into trouble with strings versus numbers. Even though your HTML input tag says `type="number"`, the value will be a string, and will need to be converted to a number before saving it to the database.

I suspect you are also intending to save the value as something like "2.7 kg", which is useful for displaying the weight, but it's a bad idea, because if you do that you will need to strip off the " kg" every time you want to calculate a new value.

Comment: Kg is defeind in a input feild for adding a produkt to a list
then i run the collection.insert({kg: kg});
and i get the value from an input
<input name="kg">
i also have the kg after the value printed inside of a "p" tag @Mikkel

Comment: Your code is not complete - I can't tell what's wrong with it... better edit the code snippets to include the relevant fields. One thing is also certain, this expression will cause an exception (probably the cause of the NaN (Not a Number))